# alternate of Masterpage of ASP.Net in JSF

Tags: asp.net, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

I got stucked in search of finding alternate of Master page in JSF.I want to convert a web application developed in ASP.Net into JSF.Now when i collided with this application's Master page , then I thought it can be handled by facelets but still I don't know that Is it right approach? 
Here's the thing, I found that facelets are alternate of user controls of ASP.net So can I use them for Master page?
Even this thing clicks me that i am going wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed Facelets. Your only other option is JSP, but it doesn't offer any templating capabilities like ASP.NET MasterPages and Facelets. Even more, JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)
- [Facelets 1.x developer guide](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html) (skip chapters 1.1-1.4 for Facelets 2.x)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)